# Css background image position animates

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-size

I am trying to make a menu that has background images that are attached an a:hover. I have different size menu links, so I figured I could have part of the image aligned left the other aligned right, and a center image that can stretch, When I apply them it works how I like except that when you first hover over it, the whole image slides down a few pixels into place. I was having the same issue when I was using just one background image I was having the same issue when using background-size contain. This is happening in Chrome, Firefox and Ie. Windows 7.

```css
li#menubg1 a:hover, ul li li#menubg1 a:hover {
    background: url("D:\hoverleft.png") no-repeat left, url("D:\hoverright.png") no-repeat right, url("D:\hovermiddle.png") no-repeat center;
    background-size: auto, auto, 100% 34px;
}
```

Comment: will adding background-attachment: fixed; stop the sliding issue?

Comment: that made it disapear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    transition: background-size 0s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background-size 0s ease-in;
    -web-kit-transition: background-size 0s ease-in;
```

I think I found the answer to my question